# Taking shoes off before closing a deal - is there an history evidence?

Tags: history, book-of-ruth

In bible ([Ruth 4,7](https://biblehub.com/text/ruth/4-7.htm)) it's written that before closing a deal, it was used that one of the sides took his shoes off:

> Now this was the manner in former time in Israel concerning redeeming and concerning changing, for to confirm all things; **a man plucked off his shoe, and gave it to his neighbour**: and this was a testimony in Israel.

In Talmud there is a debate which side took his shoes off. One says it was Boaz (Buyer), and the second opinion says it was the second side (seller).

My question is if we can find some evidence in the history science which can supports one of the opinions?